# Sitecore TDS on deploy cannot find map.xml

Tags: sitecore, tds

I have created a Sitecore TDS project and when I try to package an update file, I get the following error:

> The following exception occured opening the IconPath map: Could not
>   find a part of the path '{project path}\IconCache\Map.xml'

I'm not sure how I can fix this.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'd try contacting Hedgehog Support, they will easily help you figure this one out. It's a very weird error since this looks as if your package is trying to include icons. Try open your TDS in XML mode and remove the `<Icon>` instance for this specific icon?

Comment: Thanks.  I'm new to TDS and haven't found any reference to Hedgehog Support anywhere, which is why I posted here.  Is there a support contact somewhere?

Comment: My error went away!  I don't believe I did anything to help the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

- Does the Map.xml file exist in the target location?
- Can TDS write to the target location, e.g. is the file read only or are there insufficient privileges.

If neither of these solve your problem then contact Hedgehog support.

Comment: It has obj in the path, which makes me think TDS is writing it.  Other files are written without error.

Answer (score 0):

That is a very odd error, as the icon cache shouldn't really be a part of the update package. How are you packaging the update file? Are you configuring the Update Package tab in the TDS project properties to generate packages on build for a specific build configuration?

Comment: This is a new configuration that does have the package tab setup to generate packages.  Oddly enough, the error went away and now I don't know why!